# How to remove additional padding from a WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

By default a WPF `TextBlock` seems to have additional top and bottom padding applied. I wish this wasn't so.

- I've tried setting negative padding, but got an exception:

  > *0,-10,0,0' is not a valid value for property 'Padding'.*
- I've tried setting the `LineHeight` property, to no apparent effect.

This is how the TextBlock looks in Blend. I've marked the problematic portion with maroon red.

[image: the red area should be removed]

Comment: If you have an answer you should post it as such, answers do *not* belong into the question, also make sure to accept it once you are allowed to.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Some research and [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543887/285795) guided me to the right answer, which is setting the following properties:

```
<TextBlock LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
           LineHeight="20"/> <!-- Or some other value you fancy. -->
```

Comment: what if want to remove from the bottom too?

Answer (score 12):

This is probably part of the font which is `Segoe UI` by default, try `Segoe` instead for example. *(You cannot assign negative padding but you could assign negative `Margins`, e.g.: `Margin="0,-3,0,0"`)*

Answer (score 7):

This space is not padding, but part of the font, reserved for accents above and below characters.

The accepted answer makes the line height smaller than the font height.

Comment: This might be better as a comment