# How to remove text block's padding in uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Recently I found that uwp render `TextBlock` with vertically margin in default.

For example, I wrap a `TextBlock` in a `Border`.
The red rectangle maybe the safe space redered by `TextBlock`.

On Android, we can set

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

So how to remove the red rectangle space on uwp?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I worked out a solution:
Set

```
<TextBlock LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
           LineHeight="44"/>
```

Refer to [How to remove additional padding from a WPF TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543846/how-to-remove-additional-padding-from-a-wpf-textblock/7568216)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want this, and Didn't you tried this ?:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="GreenYellow">
   <TextBlock x:Name="tb" FontSize="48" Text="Color" Margin="0,-15,0,-10"/>
   <Border.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="3" />
   </Border.RenderTransform>
 </Border>
```

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The red rectangle area I marked is the space created by Text itself. On Android, we can set 
'android:includeFontPadding="false"'. Is there a property in uwp?